# Many to many relation - have I done it right?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

The idea is pretty simple. I have a list of tags. When I create a question I want to add some tags to it.

Models:

```
public class QuestionModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public String Content { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TagModeltoQuestionModel> Tags { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<TagModel> AssignedTags { get { return Tags.Select(x => x.Tag).ToList(); } }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionViewModel // helper - not in database
{
    public QuestionModel Model { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TagModel> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class TagModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TagModeltoQuestionModel> Questions { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool Assigned { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<QuestionModel> AssignedQuestions { get { return Questions.Select(x => x.Question).ToList(); } }

}

public class TagModeltoQuestionModel // many to many
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }

    public virtual QuestionModel Question { get; set; }
    public virtual TagModel Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(QuestionViewModel questionViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _repo.Update(questionViewModel.Model, questionViewModel.Tags); // see repo code below
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(questionViewModel.Model);
}
```

Repo:

```
public void Update(QuestionModel entity, ICollection<TagModel> tags)
{
    AssignTags(entity, tags);
    Db.Attach(entity);
    Db.SaveChanges();
}

private void AssignTags(QuestionModel entity, ICollection<TagModel> tags)
{
    tags = tags.Where(x => x.Assigned).ToArray(); // remove unassigned comming form View --> Controller

    var linkedTags =
        Db.TagsToQuestions.Where(x => x.QuestionId == entity.Id);
    var linkedTagsIds = linkedTags.Select(x => x.TagId);

    var selectedTagsIds = tags.Select(x => x.Id);
    var oldTags = linkedTags.Where(x => !selectedTagsIds.Contains(x.TagId));
    var newTags = tags.Where(x => !linkedTagsIds.Contains(x.Id)).Select(x=> new TagModeltoQuestionModel{QuestionId=entity.Id,TagId=x.Id});

    foreach (var t in oldTags)
        Db.Delete(t);

    foreach (var t in newTags)
        Db.Add(t);

    Db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This works fine, though I'm not sure if this is the right way to go (in fact I implemented the whole many-to-many logic myself). Is there a smarter way to let EF do the job for me? I dug through a bunch of tutorials, but none of them worked for me.

Additionally I feel that AssignTags method could be written in a better way, so any comments concerning that also appreciated.

**EDIT**

According to haim770's answer I simplified the model the way he suggested.

My controller now looks like that:

```
public void Update(QuestionModel entity, ICollection<TagModel> tags)
{
    Db.Attach(entity);

    //these lines give the same result
    //var ids = tags.Select(y => y.Id).ToArray();
    //entity.Tags = Db.Tags.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)).ToArray();

    tags.ForEach(x => Db.Attach(x));
    entity.Tags = tags;
    Db.SaveChanges();
}
```

SaveChanges results in an error:

```
An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.
inner:
{"A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a unique index. [ Table name = TagModelQuestionModels,Constraint name = PK_TagModelQuestionModels ]
```

So how to implement it correctly?

Comment: Your question seems better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com StackOverflow is a programming related Q&A site where you should ask only specific questions with problems you might have encountered with a particular piece of code.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Partially you are right. I could instead have asked 'how to implement a many-to-many relation' because this is my real point here, but  I included the code to be more specific.

Comment: Alright, then what particular problem did you encounter with this code? What is not working? What error message did you get? StackOverflow is a Q&A site where people ask specific questions about a particular code that they are having some problems with. So what about you? What problems did you encounter with this code and what is not working? If you cannot answer those questions and are just asking for a code review or whether there are better ways to implement something, then, as I already stated in my first comment, your question is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DarinDimitrov My problem with the code was that having only QuestionModel and TagModel both having collections of each other (without TagModeltoQuestionModel). This simply didn't work - there was no working relation. I used TagModeltoQuestionModel as a workaround and posted it to show I put some effort into the problem.  Doesn't it still qualify? :(

Comment: I quote from your question: `This works fine`. So I repeat my question: `What problems did you encounter with your code? What errors or exceptions did you encounter?`.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the `TagModeltoQuestionModel` class. You could model `many-to-many` relations like this:

```
public class QuestionModel
{
    //....
    public ICollection<TagModel> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class TagModel
{
    //....
    public ICollection<QuestionModel> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

`Question` holds a reference to many `Tags` and each `Tag` holds a reference to many `Questions`.

The whole point of `Entity Framework` (like any other `ORM`) is to spare you from having to model your objects and their relations in a `database-like` way but rather let you model it in a pure `Object Oriented` way then letting the ORM do the 'dirty work' of intermediate-tables, foreign keys etc...

Comment: This worked for Create action. But update crashes (myQuestion.Tags = someTags) it complains in SaveChanges() about the keys. (It tries to re-add the tags in myQuestion.Tags instead of updating them).

Comment: Please post the full exception along with your 'Update' code.

Comment: Also, i didn't mean that changing your entities the way i recommended should make it work immediately, i just outlined the way it should be done.

In your case, after you changed your classes, did you change the database accordingly? did you let Entity Framework re-create it for you?

Comment: Yes EF receated the database. Please see the edit for more details.